# Export DataGridView SelectedRows to a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I want to transfer multiple selected rows of a `DataGridView` to a `DataTable` then set the it a datasource for my crystal report.

First I load all the data came from my database through a stored procedure.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = clsPayroll.view_Employee();
```

Then I put the code below in the print selected button where multiselection is not restricted.

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
table.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++) {
    table.Rows.Add();
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
        table.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value;
    }
}
rpt.SetDataSource(table);
```

I have some entries on my database here:

```
EMP_ID      Emp_Name    Gender  
EMP-000013  Dummy       Male    
EMP-000014  Teresa      Female  
EMP-000015  Dutcry      Male
```

When I select the rows EMP-000014 and EMP-0000015.

I expect that the crystalreport viewer will list it but instead it shows the EMP-000013 and EMP-000014

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who posted their answers and I'm sorry not to update whether I've already fixed it.

I am able to figured out why my code is not working as it used to be.

Instead of fetching data from datagridview I should use datagridview.selectedrows instead.

Here's the code

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
table.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++) {
    table.Rows.Add();
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
       table.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;

    }
}
rpt.SetDataSource(table);
```